# Como criar Capa em um Relatório usando iReport

Tags: java, ireport

Estou usando o iReport 5.5.2 e já tentei de várias formas adicionar uma capa no relatório, que é necessário, porém sem sucesso.
Já tentei adicionar o atributo isTitleNewPage na banda Title do iReport, mas isso não funcionou e procurei algum atributo para iniciar uma banda em uma nova página e depois as restantes em outra página e não funciona.
Vi em um fórum, que não me recordo o nome, um usuário informando que resolveu o problema criando dois arquivos PDF's separados e depois unindo os dois com iText, mas acredito que isso é POG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando tive a necessidade de adicionar páginas quaisquer em relatórios ou mesmo juntar vários relatórios, o caminho foi juntar os documentos com iText.

Isso não é POG! POG é usar uma ferramenta para um objetivo diferente do qual ela foi projetado.

O JasperReports (iReport é apenas o editor) foi projeto para gerar relatórios a partir de fontes de dados e não documentos contendo texto. Já o iText é projetado para criar e manipular arquivos PDF. Portanto, nada mais justo do que deixar cada ferramenta com a sua função.

Por outro lado, fiz uma breve pesquisa para saber se o pessoal do JasperReports poderia ter implementado algo específico quanto a isso e cheguei a [um blog](http://lnhomez.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/merge-multiple-jasper-reports-in-to.html) que mostra um trecho de código que permite juntar dois relatórios. Não testei a solução, mas se funcionar você pode criar um outro relatório que seja somente a capa e juntar com o relatório que contém os dados.

Veja o trecho de código:

```java
JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(url.openStream(), parameters,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(inspBean));
JasperPrint jp2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(url.openStream(), parameters,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(inspBean));

List pages = jp2 .getPages();
for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
    JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(j);
    jp1.addPage(object);
}
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp1, false);
```

Obviamente seria necessário adaptar o exemplo e verificar se a sua versão API é compatível com este método.

Comment: @utiluiz obrigado pela resposta, você salvando meus relatórios outra vez. A questão de juntar os relatórios e ser pog, falei por que pensei que o iReport já tinha uma opção para adicionar capa, ignorância minha a respeito da ferramenta. Uma solução que achei foi colocar a imagem de capa no title, e a imagem ocupou uma página toda. Com sua explicação o que fiz seja uma gambiarra para funcionar.

Comment: @adelmo00 É, realmente existem algumas técnicas colocando imagens ou um subreport, mas eu não usaria elas porque realmente são gambiarras. Bem, gambiarra ou não, o importante é que atende seus objetivos. ;)